# WebSocket connection to 'wss://{base-url}/_blazor?id='Fjsogks_I845JsidSR' Failed: on Jmeter script recording

Tags: websocket, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

Images and Js files are not loading and Getting this error on console when trying to record Jmeter script on my website. It just login the page and navigate on dashboard but non of the content on dashboard loads. Tried every solution I have come across on internet but it does not work.

[Error On console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l8ib.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can record [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) traffic with JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). Also WebSocket protocol is not supported by any JMeter's [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)

There is [**JMeter WebSocket Samplers** project](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) which adds WebSocket protocol support to JMeter but unfortunately you won't be able to record and replay (yet?), you will have to inspect WebSocket requests in your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and mimic the traffic using the Samplers provided by the aforementioned plugin.

Check out [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide) article for more information if needed.